# Can't get recipient list correctly output for PHPMailer BCC email and full name

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer, bcc

how to merge or join or map two arrays fetched from mysql db 
array full_name and array email to create one recipient list to be bcc for php mailer
and then be able to use something like:

```
$email= array();
$full_name= array();

while loop starts
array_push($email, $row['email']);
array_push($full_name, $row['full_name']);
loop ends
```

At the end of the while loop i want to merge or join two arrays as shown above
how can I do that? can anybody kindly guide me in the right direction?

```
foreach($recipients as $email => $full_name)
{
   $mail->AddBCC($email, $full_name);
}
```

Many thanks for your valuable help and advice.

Comment: That code looks reasonable - what's not working? Why not push the addresses directly into PHPMailer instead of putting them in the intermediate array?

Comment: Do you just need: `$recipients = array_combine($email, $full_name);`?

Comment: Dear Synchro, thank you very much, truly you are a star. that is exactly what I needed. I have a log file that is why I don't want to push the addresses directly into PHPMailer I need the email array for the log file.

Comment: OK, I'll repost that comment as an answer - Please accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine two matching indexed arrays into one associative array (that you can loop over with `foreach`), you need to use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). For your code that would be:

```
$recipients = array_combine($email, $full_name);
```